# Retrieve nested list from XDocument with LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Ok I want my link query to return a list of users. Below is the XML

```
<section type="Users">
    <User type="WorkerProcessUser">
        <default property="UserName" value="Main"/>
        <default property="Password" value=""/>
        <default property="Description" value=""/>
        <default property="Group" value=""/>
    </User>
    <User type="AnonymousUser">
        <default property="UserName" value="Second"/>
        <default property="Password" value=""/>
        <default property="Description" value=""/>
        <default property="Group" value=""/>
    </User>
</section>
```

And my current LINQ Query that doesn't work. doc is an XDocument

```
var users = (from iis in doc.Descendants("section")
                     where iis.Attribute("type").Value == "Users"
                     from user in iis.Elements("User")
                     from prop in user.Descendants("default")
                     select new 
                     {
                         Type = user.Attribute("type").Value, 
                         UserName = prop.Attribute("UserName").Value
                     });
```

I get an `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception. Can anyone tell me what I need to fix?

Here is my second attempt after fixing for the wrong property name. However this one does not seem to enumerate the UserName value for me when I try to use it or at least when I try to write it to the console. Also this returns 8 total results I should only have 2 results as I only have 2 users.

```
(from iis in doc.Descendants("section")
                     where iis.Attribute("type").Value == "Users"
                     from user in iis.Elements("User")
                     from prop in user.Descendants("default")
                     select new
                     {
                         Type = user.Attribute("type").Value,
                         UserName = (from name in prop.Attributes("property")
                                     where name.Value == "UserName"
                                     select name.NextAttribute.Value).ToString()
                     });
```

Comment: When you say "it does not work" is there an error, or does it just not return the values you expect (or any at all)?

Comment: I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help. I wish my reputation was high enough to upvote everyone because everyone did give me help that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `default` elements don't have a `username` attribute, `username` is a value of the `property` attribute.

And here's how your query should probably look as an alternative to what `Henk Holterman` wrote. The difference being I *selecting* at the `User` element level rather than at the `default[@property='UserName']` element level.

```
var usr = (from iis in doc.Descendants("section")
           where iis.Attribute("type").Value == "Users"
           from user in iis.Elements("User")
           select new
           {
               Type = user.Attribute("type").Value,
               UserName = (from prop in user.Descendants("default")
                           where prop.Attribute("property").Value == "UserName"
                           select prop.Attribute("value").Value).FirstOrDefault()
           });
```

Compared to your second attempt the code `from prop in user.Descendants("default")` has been moved into the anonymous type constructor and the assignment to UserName has been simplified.

Comment: Wow yea I see that now, but I'm still not sure how to select value of the username property value property.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("section[@type='Users']")
.Elements("User")
.Select(c => new
{
    Type = c.Attribute("type").Value,
    UserName = c.XPathSelectElement("default[@property='UserName']").Attribute("value").Value
});
```

You will need to add `using System.Xml.XPath;` at the top of your .cs file for the `XPathSelectElement` extension method to be found.

Comment: That gives me an XmlException saying the '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: This is XPath, not (straight) XDocument syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
var root = XDocument.Load(@"...").Root;
var ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var users = root.Descendants(ns.GetName("default")).Where(e => e.Attribute("property").Value == "UserName").Select(e => new
{
    Type = e.Parent.Attribute("type").Value,
    UserName = e.Attribute("value").Value
});
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, users.Select(u => String.Format("{0} ({1})", u.UserName, u.Type))));
```